# UI-Bootstrap Carousel won't cooperate with my Angular App. Why?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies, carousel

I've tried everything. It's like nothing I do can get this damn carousel working. It's bringing in the proper data from the controller, but it doesn't format it like a carousel -- everything's showing and the words are stacked on top of each other.

Here are my angular app dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch'])
```

Here's my markup:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_componenets/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-csp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.css">

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
```

...

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <uib-carousel class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" ng-class="{active : $first}">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>{{slide.headline}}</h1>
      <p>{{slide.byline}} on {{slide.date}}</p>
      <h3>{{slide.publication}}</h3>
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"  ng-non-bindable>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"  ng-non-bindable>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

I just don't get it. Even when I discarded doing this with `ng-repeat` and hardcoded all the data directly into the markup, the arrows still were all glitchy and went backwards or would get stuck on the second slide. I don't know, maybe there's something wrong with my dependencies. Whatever the case, it's frustrating as hell not being able to get such a "simple" component working.

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @br3w5 no...no console errors

Comment: As you want to implement a carousel with `ui-bootstrap`, don't link `angular-carousel.js` (and therefore `angular-carousel.css`). Also, as said above, check if all libraries are correctly fetched.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos, okay, I just tried taking out irrelevant dependencies, and no luck. I believe everything is correctly fetched. I think I'd get 404 errors if they weren't.

Comment: Btw, you should have at least one error, because you linked `bower_componenets/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-csp.css`. Not the cause of the not-working carousel though. Check also if `ui-bootstrap-tpls` is in the same version as `ui-bootstrap`, i.e. 0.13.4

Comment: Yeah, it's the same version.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos, you're right! That's it! It's working now. OMG, thanks for going through that with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ***uib-carousel*** syntax (notice the ***uib-*** prefix), has been introduced in angular ui-bootstrap **0.14.0**, but the version you have is **0.13.4**, where the directive is named ***carousel***, i.e. without prefix.

Either upgrade to 0.14, or if you stay in 0.13, removing the `uib-` prefix will do the trick.

Replace:

```
    <uib-carousel ...>
        <uib-slide ...>
           <!-- ... -->
        </uib-slide>  
    </uib-carousel>
```

with:

```
    <carousel ...>
        <slide ...>
           <!-- ... -->
        </slide>  
    </carousel>
```

As a side note, remove `angular-carousel.(js|css)` from the dependencies, as it is another carousel solution, but you are obviously using the ui-bootstrap one.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Michael P. Bazos does resolve your problem, but you shouldn't go that way, because it is the deprecated API.

The developers of Angular-Bootstrap decided to add a prefix (uib) to their directives and also to their angular controllers in version 0.14. Since the release, the official documentation contains only the uib-prefixed version. If you use an old version of angular-bootstrap in your project, the current documentation will not work for obvious reasons.

Therefore: Update your angular-bootstrap to the most current version (as of today, 2015-10-12, it is 0.14.1) and it will work. The solution of Michael is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Here You can find working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PrM5PSkUHJ3l8mwXMFZQ?p=preview

Since 30 March 2016 (seems to be AngularUI 1.3.0), uib-carousel and uib-slide directives have `restrict: 'A'` clause, which means they should be defined as element's attribute. This example can be found on [AngularUI homepage](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel):

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

What is more, it seems that You mess Bootstrap' carousel with AngularUI' carousel.

Comment: You are my hero today. Thanks.